# CSS aspect ratio 100vw OR 100vh depending on window size

Tags: html, css, viewport, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to place an image centered  with the height 100vh and the width auto
when the browser window width is wider than the aspect ratio of the image
and when I reduce the width of the browser window lower than the width of the shown image the width of the image should be 100vw and the height auto. Always keeping the aspect ratio of the image so the image is always shown completely either docking the width or height to the window.
No warping and always centered where it not docks to the window.

This is what I have so far. The 3 other images will be resized and repositioned in a "body onload" JS when I can read the current position and size of the image.
Yes I know that I used the class center-fit in img and div but when I change it the escalation begins

Is it maybe better to resize, place and scale the main img with JS too?

```html
 <html>
 <head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .imgbox {
            display: grid;
            height: auto;
        }
        .center-fit {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .imageOff {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          cursor: pointer
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body >
<div class="imgbox">
    <div class="center-fit">
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/400x600.png"  class="center-fit"  id="mainImage"  onclick="imgClick()" >
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png" class="imageOff"  id="lichtAus" onclick="imgClick()" style="top: 0px" visible="true" >
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png" class="imageOff"  id="ledsAus"  onclick="imgClick()" style="top: 100px" visible="true" >
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png" class="imageOff"  id="loopAus"  onclick="imgClick()" style="top: 300px" visible="true" >
   </div>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use an image placeholder service for your demo, such as https://placeholder.com.

Comment: You can combine media queries width and height...

Comment: I added a placeholder thanks but you need to view this in full page otherwise it looks kinda different. Sorry this is my very first question here.

Comment: maybe use 100vmin

Comment: Sounds as though you will be using JS to calculate the positions of the other images, but how about using object-fit contain and object- position center for your main image without having to do any calculation or media queries/ viewport ratio tests?

Comment: Could you give ma an example? I think I already tried this but either the image size was restricted to max original size, not centered or stretched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `object-fit: container;` for that.

See for [more details and alternatives](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)

```html
<html>
 <head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .imgbox {
            display: grid;
            height: auto;
        }
        .center-fit {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          object-fit: contain;
        }
        .imageOff {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0px;
          cursor: pointer
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body >
<div class="imgbox">
    <div class="center-fit">
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/400x600.png"  class="center-fit"  id="mainImage"  onclick="imgClick()" >
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png" class="imageOff"  id="lichtAus" onclick="imgClick()" style="top: 0px" visible="true" >
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png" class="imageOff"  id="ledsAus"  onclick="imgClick()" style="top: 100px" visible="true" >
        <img src= "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png" class="imageOff"  id="loopAus"  onclick="imgClick()" style="top: 300px" visible="true" >
   </div>
</div> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is stretching the image but I want to keep the aspect ratio of the image. The code I posted works for me but only in a wide browser window.  When I reduce the window width the below the image aspect ratio my image gets stretched and that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: I either don't understand your question or you have a browser which doesn't support object-fit. When you say no stretch, do you mean no stretch at all or no stretch in one direction more than in the other? My example should keep the ratio between height and width constant, while scaling the image to fill the viewport.

Comment: I clicked on run code snippet and full window view and the 400x600 image filled the whole browser window. Ignoring the aspect ratio. I probably didn't explained correctly . The image is allowed to stretch but only when keeping the ratio. So when the browser is wide enough it should have the height of the browser and the width fitting the aspect ratio leaving white space to the left and right. When I resize the browser window width to maybe 100px, keeping the height, the image should shrink down to width 100px and the height should keep aspect ratio leaving white space above and below.

Comment: Ok. If you want to keep the space, you can use object-fit: contain instead. I updated my answer. Also added a link for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I was searching for!